# iOS: Chat bubble change position of tail

Tags: swift, gradient, blur, uibezierpath

I'm trying to achive this layout
[[LAYOUT TO ACHIEVE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZGAP.jpg)]

and right now I have gradient part done, blur part done, and also bezier path mostly done. My question is that I can't replace TAIL from bottom right part to top left part (to be similar like in the picture).

[[LAYOUT ACHIEVED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0K50.jpg)]

My Code I wrote for acheiving:

```
public final class BubbleView: UIView {
    public var configuration: Configuration = Configuration.defaultConfiguration {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        super.backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let hasBlurSubview = subviews.compactMap({$0}).contains(where: {$0 is UIVisualEffectView })
        guard !hasBlurSubview else {
            return
        }

        let lineWidth = configuration.lineWidth
        
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
        
        let bottom = rect.height - lineWidth
        let right = rect.width - lineWidth
        let top = 0.0
        let left = 0.0
        
        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: right - 22, y: bottom))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 17 + lineWidth, y: bottom))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: left, y: bottom - 18), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 7.61 + lineWidth, y: bottom), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: left, y: bottom - 7.61))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: left, y: 17 + lineWidth))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 17 + borderWidth, y: top), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: left, y: 7.61 + lineWidth), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 7.61 + lineWidth, y: top))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: right - 21, y: top))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: right - 4, y: 17 + lineWidth), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: right - 11.61, y: top), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: right - 4, y: 7.61 + lineWidth))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: right - 4, y: bottom - 11))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: right, y: bottom), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: right - 4, y: bottom - 1), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: right, y: bottom))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: right + 0.05, y: bottom - 0.01))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: right - 11.04, y: bottom - 4.04), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: right - 4.07, y: bottom + 0.43), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: right - 8.16, y: bottom - 1.06))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: right - 22, y: bottom), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: right - 16, y: bottom), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: right - 19, y: bottom))
        bezierPath.close()
        
        let blurEffect = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
        blurEffect.alpha = configuration.blurAlpha
        blurEffect.frame = bezierPath.bounds
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = bezierPath.cgPath
        blurEffect.layer.mask = mask
        insertSubview(blurEffect, at: 0)
        
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)
        gradient.colors = configuration.borderGradientColors.map({$0.cgColor})
        gradient.startPoint = configuration.borderGradientStartPoint
        gradient.endPoint = configuration.borderGradientEndPoint
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shape.path = bezierPath.cgPath
        shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        gradient.mask = shape
        blurEffect.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }
}

public class Configuration {
        static var defaultConfiguration: Configuration {
            return .init(
                lineWidth: 2.0,
                blurAlpha: 0.95,
                borderGradientColors: [Assets.Colors.white05.color, Assets.Colors.white01.color],
                borderGradientStartPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5),
                borderGradientEndPoint: CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
            )
        }
        
        var lineWidth: CGFloat
        var blurAlpha: CGFloat
        var borderGradientColors: [UIColor]
        var borderGradientStartPoint: CGPoint
        var borderGradientEndPoint: CGPoint

        init(
            lineWidth: CGFloat,
            blurAlpha: CGFloat,
            borderGradientColors: [UIColor],
            borderGradientStartPoint: CGPoint,
            borderGradientEndPoint: CGPoint
        ) {
            self.lineWidth = lineWidth
            self.blurAlpha = blurAlpha
            self.borderGradientColors = borderGradientColors
            self.borderGradientStartPoint = borderGradientStartPoint
            self.borderGradientEndPoint = borderGradientEndPoint
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code for generating your chat bubbles is hard-coded with lots of "magic numbers."  You will need to map out each curve you want to draw and then construct a path that creates your desired curve.

Comment: @DuncanC I don't have much experience with bezier path and don't have much understanding with it. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @DuncanC and I can't find tutorials about right tail for bubbles.

Comment: I wrote a [**demo project**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/RoundedCornerPolygon.git) that builds rectangles with an arbitrary mix of rounded and non-rounded corners. It would be a good starting point for constructing a path that also includes a pointer.

Comment: Do you want the tail to be added between the top left and top right rounded corners, as in your image, or do you want to **change** the top left corner to be a tail? (Take a look at the chat bubbles in Apple's message app. Those tails replace either the bottom left or bottom right corner.)

Comment: @DuncanC if you look at the screenshot (LAYOUT TO ACHIEVE), that's what I want to get.

Comment: Your sample image looks to have a tail pointing UP, on the left side, in addition to having 4 normal rounded corners. Is that what you want? That's different than having a tail that points left from the top left corner.

Comment: I'd suggest extending my sample code to have different types of `PolygonPoint` structs; rounded corners and tails. It might be better to make it an enum with associated values for each type. A tail type might have an anchor corner (topLeft/topRight/bottomLeft/bottomRight and a vertical and horizontal offsetFactor (0 would be directly on the corner, 0.1 would be 10% of the way from that corner to the next corner, and 0.5 would be halfway between corners.)

Comment: @DuncanC unfortunately I can't handle your code, if you can paste here example of it https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZGAP.jpg by handling this bezier path, I would be appreciated.

Comment: You "can't handle" my code? What does that mean?

Comment: @DuncanC that mean I was not able to achieve result using your polygons

Comment: So edit your question to show what you tried.

Comment: You definitely want 4 rounded corners, plus a “tail” on the left side of the top edge? All the chat bubbles I’ve seen modify one of the 4 corners to turn that corner into a tail.

Comment: @DuncanC yes I want 4 rounded corners plus tail on top left side.

Comment: So I wrote code that generates a rectangle with 1, 2, 3, or 4 rounded corners. What did you try to update it to add a "tail"? Show your attempt and I can help you get it working.

Comment: Your sample image is crude and hard to understand. Do you want the tail pointing directly up, or up and to the left? If you want it pointing directly up, do you want it to be symmetrical? If not, why not? The way to do this is to map out the you want on graph paper showing the curved segments and straight segments, and then write code that adds those segments to your shape. Without defining the desired shape in detail you can't draw it.